# Allow Trusted Users to modify Closed As Duplicate link

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, trusted-user

There is a problem with duplicates not being handled well on the site over time as outlined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172509/report-or-automatically-fix-problematic-duplicate-patterns).  Sometimes the chain leading to the best canonical question is too long, sometimes it doesn't even link to the best canonical, sometimes it links to a deleted question, and sometimes a post closed before they changed the process will link to an unanswered question.

**I would like to request that Trusted Users (20k+) be allowed to change the Close as Duplicate link** so that those questions could all eventually be pointed towards a non-deleted non-closed answered canonical question (optimally).

I think it would be best if we had a queue for this, so that it would take multiple Trusted Users to actually implement the change.

Comment: Yes I think this is something that we should be allowed to do; though I think 20k might be a little too high seeing as smaller sites aren't going to have many of those users.

Comment: @Seth, a lot of the small sites have different privilege levels.  Trusted Users on those sites can be set to a lower amount.

Comment: That is true; but take [wordpress.se] for example, there are only 3 or 4 20k users that aren't moderators and  on [ubuntu.se] we only have 4-6 *active* 20k users.

Comment: @Seth, yep,  but I think it should be a very restricted ability, as it is pretty powerful.  I would set it higher on Stack Overflow, but thought the Trusted User nomenclature was the right one to use.  They just don't have names (or attendant privileges) for levels over 20k.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171309/after-the-duplicate-changes-we-are-no-longer-able-to-edit-the-this-question-al

Comment: Come on guys, it's related, definitely not an exact duplicate.  This is a specific feature request, not a general bug report.

Comment: it could also work if this  privilege give  to 15k+ user

Comment: yes it will be very useful i have saw many time that question in duplicate link dialog is deleted (sorry dont have link)

Comment: @LanceRoberts One day all meta questions will be closed as a duplicate of the unanswered "I did something and what I wanted to happen didn't happen".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of a few minutes ago, if you have a gold tag-badge for a tag associated with a question that's been closed as a duplicate, you can edit the duplicate links to replace, add, remove or re-arrange them.

For details, see: [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)