# Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, moderator-tools, dupehammer

As of a few minutes ago, if you have a gold tag-badge for a tag associated with a question that's been closed as a duplicate, you can edit the duplicate links to replace, add, remove or re-arrange them:

[image: edit link in duplicate banner]

[image: link editor]

[image: revision list]

These changes are tracked in PostHistory to allow anyone to detect abuse, while the results update the PostLinks table so that existing logic continues to work (I mention this because some of you may wish to lean on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for observing how this works out, once it gets updated).

#### Rationale

This has been requested for... [Oh, about four years now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172513/allow-trusted-users-to-modify-closed-as-duplicate-link). In February of 2013, Jarrod replaced the venerable but messy method of marking duplicates by editing links into the top of the post with a system that records the question IDs in a separate table and renders them as needed. This was a *huge* improvement... Not only did it make tracking the usage of duplicates much easier and more reliable, it also prevented editors from inadvertently (or intentionally...) editing out the duplicate links without reopening the question.

But it also [prevented anyone from *updating* duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171309/after-the-duplicate-changes-we-are-no-longer-able-to-edit-the-this-question-al), which was useful in cases where more than one duplicate was appropriate (for instance, "too broad" questions that consist of multiple questions, each already answered) or situations where the asker clarified their problem and a different duplicate link became appropriate.

This was clearly not ideal; some folks resorted to reopening and re-closing, while others [savagely abused bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289395/too-many-shogs-when-viewing-the-close-reason-in-the-ios-app) to work around the deficiency.

Today, that changes. Oded stepped up to implement an elegant solution: allow [users trusted to single-handedly *close* questions as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders/231212#231212) to also modify the list at will.

This stops short of fully restoring the previous capabilities - after all, there were serious downsides to that. But it should suffice to allow those most familiar with a given topic to better curate it.

Please report any bugs you find, tagging them [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) [dupehammer](/questions/tagged/dupehammer). Enjoy!

Comment: [Yes! Yes!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tKW1i.gif)

Comment: Is this feature available if you edit your relevant tag into the question, or does the same restriction about self-added tags apply?

Comment: FINALLY! Awesome! Also, suggest retitling post to "Shiny new duplicate edit feature", for versioning consistency.

Comment: Same restrictions that apply to closing as a badge-holder apply to this, @TylerH.

Comment: I love this, great stuff!

Comment: Anonymous users will be redirected towards which question?

Comment: JAL's is the best, but https://media.makeameme.org/created/yes-finally.jpg

Comment: @JAL [another version, yes!!](http://giphy.com/gifs/yes-daniel-bryan-happy-2RGhmKXcl0ViM)

Comment: Already found a bug.. [Error modal underlaps duplicate finder when attempting to add a second duplicate to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291826/242209)

Comment: [@JAL is a party pooper.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjwofYhUJEM)

Comment: Redirect doesn't happen at all if there are multiple targets, @Braiam - this is existing behavior, since it's always been possible to have multiple links in this list.

Comment: I've been wanting this for the last five years.  Thank you!

Comment: Whew! That's cool :)

Comment: When the duplicate list is edited currently the revision history just lists the post IDs of the revision list before and after the change.  Can those post IDs be actual links to those questions?

Comment: Post feature-request, @Servy

Comment: This is a lot more powerful than I originally thought it was, which is *fantastic*.  Question:  will the ability to query who changed what links around be available in SEDE, or is it already?

Comment: The data should make it into SEDE eventually, @Makoto. Probably not the easiest thing to work with in SQL, but do-able.

Comment: *Added to the list of reasons I should get a dupehammer somewhere ASAP*

Comment: Who do we need to pay off to get cross-site duplicate closure in the next round? :)

Comment: I'm [kinda skeptical](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16703/the-ability-to-link-cross-site-duplicates/16708#16708) that cross-site duplicates make sense, @DVK. Better cross-site *link-tracking* would be pretty nice, though. The Int'l sites are working on something like this right now, if you're interested: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4857

Comment: @Shog9 - some use cases 100% clearly exist (SFF=>literature; SFF=>movies). Some questions are literally full on duplicate. Not sure if volume warrants dev work

Comment: But are the answers, @DVK? Keep in mind, this can't be a feature that'd occasionally come in handy - there's a massive cost involved (above and beyond link-tracking, which is already shaping up to be expensive). So the occasional question on Lit which is reasonably well answered on SFF, or the occasional question on Server Fault which is reasonably well-answered on SO ain't gonna justify the cost (both in implementation and in education, general grief...) that would come with it.

Comment: @Shog9 - i just thought up an alternative implementation - inlcuding answers. E.g. I can post an answer that literally says "<include SO#121334>" and it will display the answer # 121334 from SO, ideally as the original poster (same way as migrated question retains original poster). This would allow dupe question to garner both great existing answers from another site AND also site-specific extra answers. Not sure how hard that'd be to develop.

Comment: That would be kinda nice, and is something we've discussed in the past. Donno if we'll ever get to it.

Comment: @Shog9 - I notice that it puts stuff in the revision history - does modifying dupe links count as a 'bump'?

Comment: How easy would it be to catch potential abuse of this feature by gold-tag-badge holders? Does editing the dupe links bump the dupe question to the front page?

Comment: Doesn't right now, but I kinda think it should; thoughts?

Comment: It definitely should bump it up on the front page. But also, are you going to implement a review queue where non-gold-badged but trusted users (e.g. >=5k) can suggest such changes, which are then reviewed in a new review queue by other trusted users, [as originally suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172513/327953)? The current solution may work well on SO, but e.g. [Travel SE has only 4 distinct gold-badged users in 5 tags](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold), one of them being a mod.

Comment: This is a fantastic addition. Give Oded a beer! One question: "Same restrictions that apply to closing as a badge-holder apply to this" You can only close/reopen once. Can you edit more than once? Not that I expect it to be necessary a lot, but nice to know before I screw up a dupe close and then fatfinger the subsequent editing too.

Comment: That restrictions belongs to the close-voting system as a whole, @josh; it's not specific to badge-holders. No restrictions on number of edits currently.

Comment: That would impose an excessive amount of complexity, @mts; moderators can help to pick up slack in cases where needed.

Comment: Sounds great! One question. A mistake I often make is: Vote to close for some other reason; realize it's a duplicate; now I want to (1) take back my close vote and (2) substitute a dupehammer. I can do the former but not the latter. Will that now become possible?

Comment: No, changing votes isn't in the cards any time soon, @matt; adds complexity to too many other things. Best to just hold your vote until certain.

Comment: Thx, I guessed this would be the case but just checking.

Comment: Is there a concern of edit wars, or of people "hijacking" duplicate questions to point to their own answers or questions? I would say there are multiple incentives to do that: more upvotes, FAQ position, more views...

Comment: Looks like you totally forgot [about the app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291885/gold-badge-holder-changes-to-duplicates-are-not-displayed-in-ios-app)(s). (most likely also in android, I don't bother to submit a report because it's pointless.)

Comment: I do have some concern there, @Kobi. But, edit wars are already possible (as is editing in a link to your own posts, or even just dropping comments). We'll be monitoring it.

Comment: Apps will have to wait on the API for editing support, @Shadow. Note that the API *also* fails to return all linked questions, which will prevent the apps from supporting that too - this is a new bug, which only shows up when dealing with questions that have had their linked duplicates edited.

Comment: @Shog9 not expecting to edit via the app, just see the list of questions chosen by the mod/hammer. (i.e. same way it's shown on web)

Comment: Yeah, that's an API bug (or omission) @shadow - feel free to post a report, or I'll get to it maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Linked to it in the first comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291885/gold-badge-holder-changes-to-duplicates-are-not-displayed-in-ios-app

Comment: Kinda late to the party, here, but I just recently used this for the first time, and I don't see this mentioned yet. Do these edits show up anywhere in our history? I can't seem to find any indication that I did a dupe edit anywhere in my _all actions_, _votes_, _revisions_, etc.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, @Mike - wanna write up a feature-request?

Comment: [Done and done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292110). Cheers!

Comment: @Shog9 I have a question about that new option. If for instance, someone other than myself closed a question such as this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/42799023/ with a duplicate and that (if) I were to add to it being this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/3800292/ - In adding it, would it take away a close vote for me, and/or for the person who originally closed it or not at all? Are there any (side) effects? And if I had closed it and added another reference link, does that count for 2 close votes? (one vote for each reference duplicate/link)?

Comment: If the question is already closed, editing the links doesn't use any close votes, @Fred-ii-

Comment: Thanks for the info, this was a *"need to know"* question, *cheers* @Shog9

Comment: [Found a small bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296466), where the "edit" link is incorrectly displayed if the question author is also a gold badge holder and the question is flagged but not actually closed yet.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't see it mentioned anywhere... is there a limit to the number of duplicates that can be added to the post? The highest I've seen is five.

Comment: 5 is the max, @TylerH

Answer (score 83):

Yes! Yes! Yes!

This is an excellent power tool for us as gold tag badge holders. It makes our job of closing questions as duplicates much easier.

I have personally often had questions which I closed as duplicate of another question and someone else came with a much better duplicate. I wished I could reopen and close again, but that wasn't possible of course.

This feature brings much more than I hoped for: we can just edit the list, we can add more than one duplicate (very helpful for 2-in-1 questions). No need to go through the reopen and reclose procedure any more. No need to ping some other gold tag badge holder to assist. Wonderful!

Comment: "our job of closing as duplicate much easier." but they are already closed as duplicates.

Comment: Yes, but if the duplicate doesn't seem to fit entirely after a comment or two, it is nice to have the ability to adjust the duplicate for a better fitting one.

Comment: As an example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42597539/993547). The cause can be two things: the server sending chunked or the automatic deflation. I don't have a duplicate giving both options. Now I can vote to close as duplicate of both of them. No need to readjust if OP removed the automatic deflation and it still doesn't seem to work. @Braiam

Comment: Meh, that's an unclear question, and should be closed as unclear. I rather prefer that the abilities to unilaterally close question is extended to other reasons rather than this feature.

Comment: (Getting off-topic here, but the question was immediately clear to me, maybe because I experienced the same issue three days ago) Extending the close vote privileges with other reasons is also still on my wishlist @Braiam

Comment: I truly agree with your comments @PatrickHofman

Comment: *I wished I could reopen and close again, but that wasn't possible of course.* you sure about that? Cause I think you can do that?

Comment: No. You have just one cycle.

Answer (score 46):

This is *soooo* nice!

The most important *sub-feature* about this feature is the ability to finally *add* additional similar threads to the duplicate question. This does not necessarily need to be *the* exact duplicate, but there are often 2-3 more very closely related topics already been asked.

[image]

Previously, as a site-moderator, I often used *strategic close-voting* to achieve this! ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

For non-gold/diamond users, could you provide a way to submit multiple duplicates as a close reason?

For instance, [I wrote a comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407448/the-type-could-not-be-found-when-running-my-smsservice-svc-file), but I'm afraid that [the comment gets deleted when the review is done](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate), leaving only one duplicate link on the post, unless a gold/diamond notices.

Comment: 3 years late, but *multiple* users can close a question as a dupe of multiple targets without intervention from gold-badge users or moderators, if they each CV the question as a dupe of a different target. The system will automatically close it as a duplicate of each of the targets suggested.

Answer (score 17):

This is really awesome, I don't have to coordinate multiple people's duplicate votes to close against multiple questions!

but can we clean up all that unused whitespace? It looks really ugly and unnatural:

> [image]

compared to this:

> [image]

Comment: You only get the whitespace if you can edit, which seems reasonable given you'd probably *want* to notice.

Comment: @Shog9 So high rep users can't have pretty things? :(

Comment: If you want pretty, [I got you covered](https://www.amazon.com/Girlie-Glue/dp/B00OKYTDRI)

Comment: @Shog9 It's not hard. See, [I fixed it.](https://i.imgur.com/fZOdIYL.png)

Comment: [And another example for completeness.](https://i.imgur.com/xSFbSyJ.png)

Comment: @ɥʇǝS Does your fix factor in [long titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyu5e.png)?

Comment: @Robotnik [Yes, it does.](https://i.imgur.com/dWsyvOy.png)

Comment: @Robotnik It can definitely get a little hairy at times ([1](https://i.imgur.com/1wZVRZe.png), [2](https://i.imgur.com/Xb9fFMg.png), [3](https://i.imgur.com/gHChcD5.png)) but considering SE doesn't try to fit the title into any kind of uniform pattern (just look at where "x answers" appears in each of those screenshots) I don't really think it's that bad.

Comment: just put the link position: absolute on the top line of the box instead!

Answer (score 12):

Is it possible to expand this? Perhaps allow people who aren't moderators or gold badge holders to submit suggested duplicates after a closure?

On Software Engineering, there are no people with gold badges and only 27 silver badges have been awarded in only 8 tags.

Even looking at other large sites, it seems like there aren't a ton of gold badges. Super User has only awarded 12 gold badges and most are 5 or fewer users. Ask Ubuntu has awarded 5 gold badges and only command-line has more than 3 people.

Stack Exchange is built on spreading out the moderation tasks across the community. I understand the thought that gold badge holders understand a particular topic well enough to identify duplicates and handle linking questions. But on sites that don't have sufficient users with these powers, there's no good alternatives.

I'm debating starting a question on Meta Software Engineering to allow people to point out duplicates, or even suggesting that people flag for moderator attention since we have 0 users outside of the moderator team who can use this functionality. But this doesn't seem sustainable in the long run.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is an edge case on most sites. If you're not currently closing a huge number of questions as duplicates, I doubt there'll be a regular need to change or expand links... But, we'll see how it pans out - easy enough to track how often moderators are called on to do this.

Comment: @Shog9 We have [1965 questions closed as duplicate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ayes) out of a total of [9533 closed questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes). That's just over 20% of our closures are duplicates. Per question close stats, duplicate has been 5% of the closures over the past 30 days. It would be easier if more people could edit these before the duplicate questions fell off the recently asked questions. Maybe the data team should see if this really is an edge case?

Comment: 5%, yes, but that's 21 questions @Thomas - maybe one per business day. If *every single one of them* required editing, that might be considered a small burden, but how many actually need it?

Answer (score 11):

While the revision history has the change, the post itself shows no indication that the dupe target has been changed. So, we have "modified by muru" in the active questions page, but if you go the question, no change anytime in last year. O.o And if the question has never been edited, no link to the revision history either. Since the change is displayed as a revision, perhaps update (or add) the "edited by X" link?

Compare with the Community-bumping issue, where posts now have a notice stating the reason for the bumping. Some sort of visual indication that Mjolnir had wrought change would be nice.

Comment: Ah, Oded *did* get bumping in - cool, I'd missed that. I could see putting a small "edited by..." note in the header.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to muscle memory, I reopened and closed to change the duplicate link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588300/repeated-first-occurence-of-an-element). However, in hindsight, I probably did the right thing.

The user who originally marked the question as a duplicate posted a comment explaining how the question is a duplicate of the link that they chose. I then reopened the question and marked it as a duplicate of another question; my answer to that question clearly debunks what the other user said in the comments. Had I edited the duplicate link in-place, their comment would no longer make sense, unless I followed up with another comment saying I changed it (since, realistically, the revision history isn't going to be the *first* place most people will think of looking in situations like this).

It would be nice if editing duplicate links in-place also modified the "marked as duplicate" notice on the question page, but as I understand if it is not feasible.

Comment: I've thought this, too, but the "marked as a duplicate" notice only says that the post was closed as a duplicate by certain users, without naming the duplicate target. It might be better to alter the header to include the name(s) of the user(s) who suggested that particular duplicate target.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) / [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

If I edit the duplicates, it shows up nicely in the post edit history and its timeline. However, at present it's missing from the `all actions` tab in my profile, which would also be good to have.

Comment: [Add the new duplicate link edit events to the user's own history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292110/add-the-new-duplicate-link-edit-events-to-the-users-own-history)

Answer (score 4):

This is a great improvement!

But concerning **gold-badges**: Since those are awarded for a fixed amount of answers / upvotes, the bar is constantly lowered over time. That affects many aspects of SO sites. A gold-badge is a crude but generally sensible benchmark. But it's also a moving target. And it's constantly moving downhill. SO is not young enough any more to ignore the effects of age.

There should be an element to balance this. Like: gold-badge plus a positive score over the last x years. A pilot license requires active use to be maintained, too.

Comment: This is intentional - the hope is that the number of privileged closers increases with the need for more curation as a topic ages.

Comment: I think it would be more useful to compare the number of gold-badge users to the traffic: maybe the proportion does not increase? It's also notable that a number of gold-badge users may NOT participate in curation/edition. Just because they happen to have the privilege does not mean they use it (often). It is tiring to shovel crap all day long, after all; I certainly got tired of attempting to read C++ questions, now I just wait for them to pop up in the "hot on the network" list.

Answer (score 2):

What about expanding this feature so that it can also be used by the user who asked the question? Since the asker of the question can close their own question as a duplicate on their own (by clicking the "This solved my problem" button), it would make sense if they are also be able to decide on their own which question their question is a duplicate of.

In case there is a risk of abuse, it could be enabled only for users who have the View Close Votes privilege, so that only users who have the privilege to vote to close or reopen their own questions have the privilege to edit the duplicate list. Also if a user abuses this feature, a moderator or gold tag badge holder could be able to decide to not allow a specific user to use this feature, gold tag badge holders being able to do so only to users who have already used this feature a certain amount of times on questions with the tag that the tag badge holder has a gold badge for.

Also I think that [Thomas Owens' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291875/349538) is a good idea, so that any user can submit suggested duplicates.