# Error modal underlaps duplicate finder when attempting to add a second duplicate to a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Steps to reproduce:

1. Edit a duplicate question and attempt to add the same question as a second duplicate.

Expected behavior:

I should see an error telling me I can't add a question as a duplicate twice.

Actual Behavior:

I can't see the error alert/modal, it's hidden by the dupe picker.

[image: Dupe Picker]

Google Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

macOS Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32)

**EDIT July 28th, 2017:**

There seems to be regression on this bug.  I just reproduced this again today.

Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)

[image: Bug]

Comment: Bloody z-index values...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

z-index indeed. Looks like something changed with z-indexes between when I originally wrote the error popup code to when this got released.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and fix!

Comment: Fast bug find, fast bug fix. Efficient!

Comment: I think this bug is back, I was just able to reproduce this on Stack Overflow.