# A return button for the new duplicate edit thing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, moderator-tools, dupehammer

The [new duplicate edit thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/321340) is great!
A bug/feature that caught my eye:

When I go to the duplicate list edit menu but choose not to edit anything, there is no button to go back.
I have to use the browser navigation instead.
I'd prefer to have a "back to question" or "cancel" button.
Is the lack of such a button intentional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a great big link at the top of the page - takes you right back to the question :)

---

Got a cancel button added to the page - with you in the next build.

Comment: Oh, I didn't parse the question title as a link. When I edit a question or see the edit history, there is a more explicit button. So: Is it possible to make the link more obvious to an idiot? :)

Comment: I'll see about adding a cancel button :)

Comment: Ah, someone else who doesn't read titles.

Comment: @Shog9 - now you know. It's a thing.

Comment: Excellent! // @Shog9 Someone else who doesn't read what? :)