# Gold badge holder changes to duplicates are not displayed in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, ios-app, dupehammer

When gold badge holder is adding multiple questions [using the new mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links), the iOS app only shows a single duplicate (the original target).  It would be great if all of the duplicate links were shown instead of just a single duplicate.

[For example](//stackoverflow.com/q/42589223/2415822):

On the website:

> [image: Image of duplicate question in website]

In the iOS app:

> [image: Image of duplicate question in app]

Comment: Multiple duplicates are shown https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLatd.png

Comment: @Cai Not this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42589223/2415822

Comment: I guess that's a bug with the new fancy multiple dupe edit stuff then (I see you edited the list, and the app is only showing the original dupe), the app has shown multiple dupes for a long time

Comment: @Cai Yes, the app shows multiple dupes correctly if they were closed the old, incorrect way as seen in Too Many Shogs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Kppr.png

Comment: A question is closed as multiple dupes if it gets different dupe votes before closing; nothing incorrect about that. As far as I can see the only time it doesn't show is if the dupes are added *after* closure.

Comment: @Cai is correct, it's a bug in the new mechanism/app integration.

Comment: @JAL the old way is NOT incorrect. Users without gold badge can also close questions, and it's totally valid and correct. And those will show just fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I understand.  At the time, my only example was the Shog way of triggering a server error when hammering.

Comment: @JAL this is only for a single user (mod or gold badge user) who want to choose more than one target. Multiple 3k users could always do that, and still  can and it's showing fine, that's what Cai (and me) are trying to say. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, I get that now.  Thank you for clarifying and editing the question.

Comment: @JAL what about revisions? I don't have iOS device so can't test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API (and as result the mobile apps) wasn't updated to take account of edits to the duplicates list - it was only looking at the original list of duplicates from when the question was closed as duplicate.

This has now been corrected.