# Add the new duplicate link edit events to the user's own history

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

Gold badgers can now [edit the link list on questions closed as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824). However, there seems to be no record of having made these edits anywhere in the user's own history. One would think they might be shown in the *revisions* tab, or possibly *votes*, or even under *all*, somehow, but I don't believe they're anywhere to be found. The only place to find evidence of these edits appears to be on the questions themselves.

This seems a simple oversight, given that pretty much every other content change we make is conveniently available for our own later review.

Please make some sort of record of these edits available to us somewhere in our user pages.