# Let gold tag badge duplicates prevail above those of other close voters

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I just [closed a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46766885/993547) as duplicate of another with my gold tag badge dupe-hammer ([timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46766885/timeline)).

I used another duplicate target as the one another user suggested which had just one vote until the time I voted to close. However, this first duplicate (which I found less useful than mine), was still on top in the duplicate notification.

Can we force the duplicate that was chosen by the gold tag badge holder to be on top when closing the question? (Or at least when it outnumbers the existing close votes.)

Comment: This definitely makes sense. The dupe targets in the notification should be listed in order of how many votes they got. Since gold badge hammer-wielders and mods effectively have 5 votes, their targets should have more votes than any other target, and thus be on top.

Comment: As a workaround, you should be able to [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) them.

Comment: That is what I did now but it feels as a step too much @JoshCaswell

Comment: Well same should apply to any binding close vote. But since you can edit the list anyway, this issue is pretty minor. :)