# Closing question causes a bump?

Tags: support, bug, vote-to-close, closed-questions, bump

Recently [I closed a question on the Stack Overflow PT as duplicate](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255188/listagem-de-arraylistobj-java), and this question was bumped to the home page, as can be seen in the images:

Close banner with timestamp:

> [image]

Homepage with timestamp:

> [image]

However, [according to this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/310559), closing is no reason for a question to be bumped.

What could have happened in this case? There was no editing in the post before or after the closing or until the publication of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to closing the question (which didn't bump on its own), you edited the [list of duplicates](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/255188/revisions):

> [image: revision history]

As this is [a new-*ish* feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links), it is likely that it caused the last modified date of the question to change.

In [one of the answers in the feature announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291904/178816), this behavior is also described by @muru:

> While the revision history has the change, the post itself shows no indication that the dupe target has been changed. So, we have "modified by muru" in the active questions page, but if you go the question, no change anytime in last year.

Comment: This has been occurring with me in questions that I can close by myself as a duplicate only.

Comment: Yep true. No need for rep, it's visible in the [question revisions](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/255188/revisions). I was going to post answer using [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fPp.png), feel free to use it yourself. :-)

Comment: @Articuno so please link to relevant question which you didn't edit its duplicates list.

Comment: Edit the list of duplicates is the reason for the question being bumped? In all that I closed and were bumped, I edited the list adding other relevant questions. Then that's it. :)

Comment: @Articuno indeed. It might be an overlook aka bug, can't really know. But this is surely the reason.

Comment: @ShadowWizard when this feature was implemented folks expressed [concerns about potential for edit wars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links#comment948025_291824) and Shog shared it. So, bump looks like [meta-tag:status-by-design]

Comment: @gnat true, that's a good point.