# When should the "Visit chat" section be visible?

Tags: support, bug, status-review, sidebar, android

On some questions (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326766/339911)) I see the "Visit chat" section which refers to the current community chat page:

> [image]

Other questions don't have such a section. Moreover on several questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847960/which-greedy-initializer-list-examples-are-lurking-in-the-standard-library)) I see the section only when responsiveness is enabled (update: now I don't see it anymore here).

What's the expected situations when a user sees such section? Is it a bug that section is not visible after switching to non-responsive mode?

Tested on Android 8 Chrome 73.0.3683.90, Firefox 66.0.2

Unable to reproduce on iOS 12.2 Chrome almost same version (73.0.3683.68).

In private mode (i.e. logged out) I see the full "people chatting" block here:

> [image]

After looking closely to iOS Chrome behavior I noticed that “Visit chat” block shortly appears while page reloading:

> [image]

Comment: I assume if people were chatting in chatrooms linked to the site you're browsing you would see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMyd3.png That site you're has users that are not that talkative ...

Comment: @rene Actually it shows "Visit chat" before that box: "7 people chatting" gets fully loaded. Try disabling responsiveness and enabling it again; note the sidebar while the page loads. BTW [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326766/why-does-adding-a-duplicate-bump-a-question-if-marking-it-as-a-duplicate-in-the) is the question in the screenshot.

Comment: No repro for me @Blue

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257677/how-are-the-chatrooms-shown-in-the-sidebar-selected

Comment: Might be some userscript messing around with your page contents, I also can't reproduce in any way. (Tried resizing screen, dev tools to mimic mobile screen etc.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard user script on mobile Chrome? :) I'm on Android now.