# Why has "visit chat" without any chatroom started appearing in the sidebar?

Tags: bug, chat, sidebar

I have noticed recently relatively often in the sidebar a short box saying "visit chat" in places where I was used to see selection of chatrooms.

This happens also on sites which have quite a lot of activity in chat. Here is a screenshot from Mathematics Stack Exchange:

[image: Screenshot]

I thought that maybe this happens if the linked questions take too much space — but after trying a bit, I saw the same on a question without any linked questions:

[image: Screenshot]

In short, I do not really notice a pattern — sometimes I see "Visit chat", sometimes I see "n people chatting" with two example rooms.

**Question:** Is this a bug? Did some recent changes influence the behavior of the sidebar? Or was it always like this — but I simply did not notice?

I have seen this bug report: [Visit chat section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326771). It seems to be mainly about Android — I have observed this in Chrome, under Windows, on the full site (not on the mobile version). But I won't object to closing as a duplicate — if this is a report for the same bug. (Even in such case, it would be nice if some other users could confirm whether they noticed the same behavior.)

A screenshot showing what I typically saw in that place can be found, for example, here: [How are the chatrooms shown in the sidebar selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257677)

Comment: It's likely taking only rooms where there was activity in the last X hours, so maybe a check to verify there is at least one such room has been dropped. (Otherwise just don't show that section.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I think that X is 1 hour. "y users active in z rooms the last 60 minutes" (from inspect mode)

Comment: It will show "n people chatting" when there are at least two rooms in which a message was posted in the last 20 minutes...and "Visit chat" after 20 minutes. I just tested it on chat.meta

Comment: and politics.SE

Comment: @Wolgwang That is interesting. (I might try to do some experiment along those line by myself.) If this is how it works, the sites which only have one active chatroom have the disadvantage that the room will never be advertised in this way.

Comment: But now I am also seeing "n people chatting" for the rooms which the last message was posted before 40 minutes!

Comment: Some related experiments were done [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2/conversation/experiments-related-to-https-meta-stackexchange-com-questions-377537-why-has-vi)