# How can I change which question the current question is a duplicate of?

Tags: feature-request, support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, retracted-close-votes

I would imagine this is a fairly common situation, but I haven't found it discussed:

1. I vote to close a question as a duplicate of a specific other
   question.
2. The asker edits the question so that it's no longer a duplicate of
   the question I chose.
3. I retract my vote.
4. The edited question is a duplicate of a different question.
5. I can't vote to close because I already voted and retracted.

If I know right away that the edited question is a duplicate of a different question, how can I switch the question that it's a duplicate of without retracting my vote?

There should be a way to this because otherwise I have to keep my vote for a question that the current question is **not** a duplicate of, or I have to retract my vote and lose the ability to vote that the question really is a duplicate (of some other question).

Is there a way to do this, and if not can we create a way to do it?

Example from today:

I voted to close [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94118/are-these-actives-permitted-on-tishbav-after-midday) on Mi Yodeya as a duplicate. The question was then edited and I retracted my close vote. In the [comment there](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94118/are-these-actives-permitted-on-tishbav-after-midday#comment308454_94118) (I can't guarantee how long it will still be there) I pointed out that it might be a duplicate of a different question, but I was unable to cast a close vote.

Comment: @PolyGeo Now that I see that post it probably is a duplicate, although perhaps it is a different emphasis.

Comment: Also relevant: [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/323179)