# Editing the duplicate list doesn't really work on mobile with the new responsive design

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, responsive-design

When trying to [add a duplicate target to a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/295232) on my iPhone, I'd like to paste a URL in the box where you're supposed to 'search, or enter a question link or numeric id'. However, the beginning of this box is hidden from view, and scrolling to the left doesn't work, as the dialog is clipped:

[image]
[image]

Long pressing the part of the box, to bring up the context menu with the Paste option doesn't work. I have a workaroud: type a long text like "testtesttesttesttesttest" and eventually it will become visible, so that you can Select All and then Paste, but it's rather cumbersome. It takes so long that a GIF of the screencast is more than 3x the maximum size for embedding via imgur, so you'll have to settle for [this YouTube link](https://youtu.be/-cecY9KEqNc) instead.

Comment: Not a fix, but I find that if I'm not in desktop mode when on that page, the box is much more usable: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF4at.jpg

Comment: While using 50% zoom and landscape mode I am able to see the entire box. But this is still a pain to do.