# Cannot edit leftmost tags on a mobile device in the new responsive design

Tags: bug, tags, editor, responsive-design, inline-tag-editor

When I'm on a mobile device with a narrow viewport, I am unable to edit or remove tags that are on the left hand side of the tag edit bar. I am only able to reach the rightmost tag or, if it's short, the second-to-rightmost tag. At full width I can place my cursor anywhere in the tag editor, but at a narrower width I cannot pan the tag editor over to the left to place my cursor over there.

If I want to edit any tags other than the rightmost 2 right now I have to disable responsiveness.

Repro:

1. Use your mobile device.
2. Open this question.
3. Try to figure out how to remove or edit the "bug" tag on this question with the responsive design on, in the full editor and (if you have access to it) in the inline tag editor.

If you can actually reach it somehow please let me know.

OS: Android 8.0.0, OxygenOS / Browser: Chrome 70

Comment: You can, by deleting all the tags and re-add the ones you want to keep :P It reminds me of my question [Editing the duplicate list doesn't really work on mobile with the new responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318115/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel Ok, that works! ;) Somehow I feel like it's supposed to be a bit easier than that...