# Responsive design makes it impossible to select a mod message template on mobile

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, responsive-design

I just tried to select a mod message template to compose a mod message. However, since that's basically impossible without a mouse (a complaint for another time), I switched to mobile. However, I got... this:

[image]

I can't select a template, and I can't side scroll to get the options in view.

Comment: Quick fix: get one of your co-mods who's on a computer to do it instead this time.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I would laugh if it turns out they can't switch to chat either so their only option would be to email the team ... "quick fix"  ...

Comment: This dialog probably suffers from the same problems as the [duplicate finder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318115/295232).

Comment: 27% battery at 11AM?  I predict a sad day in Mith-land. :-)