# Is there a limit to how many questions can be added to the duplicate list?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

A question can be a duplicate of more than one question. Moderators and users with gold tag badges can add questions to the list of questions that a given question is a duplicate of. I was recently closing a question as a duplicate and I saw a lot of similar questions. This led me to wonder: Is there any limit to how many questions I can add to the list? Can I just keep on adding more questions forever, or will the system stop me at some point?

Comment: [This seems to imply **3**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/282094) but it's not clearly and boldly written, 3 is the most I've seen.

Comment: @Rob There was one with four targets that got deleted today.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Can you find one with more, give us a FAQ link, or edit the Sandbox question to see how many you can stuff in there.

Comment: @Rob Don't have a gold badge. 10k+ users can see an example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341621/what-are-stack-exchanges-policy-regarding-historical-data), and I've pinged someone who probably knows more about it.

Comment: It's an interesting related question, now that [we have three vote close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364007/282094) (even [single vote](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/655/9731) close on a couple of sites), if that affects the length of the duplicate list.

Answer (score 10):

Can't find an official post on this, but the highest amount of dupe-targets I've encountered is five. I wrote [a quick SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1174962/sort-questions-by-highest-amount-of-duplicate-targets) sorting the posts by number of dupe targets coming from it, and this seems to confirm that "five" assumption.

```sql
SELECT 
  pl.PostId AS [Post Link],
  COUNT(LinkTypeId) AS 'Number of dupe-targets'

FROM PostLinks pl

WHERE pl.LinkTypeId=3 

GROUP BY pl.PostId

ORDER BY 'Number of dupe-targets' DESC
```

[image: screenshot of results]

Answer (score 9):

Apparently I should have just tried this before asking. The "add" button is no longer clickable (it is faded out) once there are five questions in the list:

[image: Screenshot showing ability to add when there are only four questions]

[image: Screenshot showing the inability to add when there are five questions]

Comment: It's possible that this is just the UI, and you can fudge the request to allow for more targets.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog there is a server side check as well, the 'save' call returns a 500 error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5xUF.png