# Can the privilege requirements increase in a site? Can you lose them in that case?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

For example, if you have "edit post" privilege by having 1000 reputation in a given Stack community, could the community become more popular and raise this privilege to 2000 reputation? Would in that case result in the user losing that privilege?

Comment: You can definitely lose privileges if your rep falls under the threshold (e.g. due to serial voting reversal, or a large enough number of downvotes), so I guess the answer is yes, that could happen if the rep requirements for a privilege were ever changed. But I don't think those requirements can be changed on a per-site basis, except when the site itself goes from private beta to public beta, or from public beta to permanent. I'm pretty sure the community of the site can't decide to change them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/1135948

Comment: See the first bullet, which links to a [longer explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387045/323179).

Comment: @Laurel I think that if this question is to be closed as duplicate it should be closed under your second link instead of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privileges depend on the current user's reputation. I don't recall having seen privilege thresholds being increased in established sites.

One typical case that causes a privilege threshold change occurs on sites in Beta. The privilege thresholds are lower than regular sites (full or graduated sites) to allow private beta users to use certain site features.

Besides the privileges threshold change, users might also lose privileges when their reputation is reduced. Reputation might be reduced due to downvotes, retired upvotes and answer acceptation, posts with a positive score being deleted, and users who have upvoted their posts being deleted or when a user offers a bounty.

Suspensions cause the user reputation to be temporarily set to 1.

Comment: We used to do it every time a site "graduated" - we just don't generally do it anymore. For more information, you can see my answer - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381749/how-should-a-newly-graduated-site-decide-when-to-request-reputation-threshold-ch/387045#387045