# Rules for closing the question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, vote-to-close

I have bad experience today on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64203540/timezone-getdstsavings-observesdaylighttime-equivalent-in-java-8?noredirect=1#comment113533783_64203540) that is closed.

1. I see it was decided by single person? Will that be previously by group of people vote then close right?
2. Why there is no time interval to questioner to improve their answer before anyone decides on  closing it?
3. why we are allowing multiple duplicates allowed to add? This makes even the reviewer not knowing the exact duplicates they are adding. :(
4. Will it be feasible to tag/@mention like moderator in such situation that needs help?

Kindly let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Duplicate isn't ordinary closure. The question is fine and fits the site, just was asked before. No need for five people to decide that, in most cases and it can't be "improved" since it's already good enough for the site.

Comment: This question asks 4 questions in one, which is discouraged and also a close reason.

Comment: To be frank, if i ask this as four different questions, i cannot emphasise the problem severity on `close` perspective. Also the end user dont have such luxury of time. But anyway Thanks!

Comment: Why was that a "bad experience"?  Your question was answered,  by pointing you to existing  answers.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I did already searching on stack overflow and other sites, now after raising a question if some one close your question and says again go through, it is not fair. At least the reviewer should pin point the real duplicate question where he finds same question / expected answer. or at least he can suggest with out closing it if he is not sure and suggesting too many. Is it close will earn some points?

Comment: @chrisneilsen So now every question can be closed with some suggestions and then get reopned? is that an expectation to keep the stack overflow clean from duplicates?

Comment: Well, 'Also the end user dont have such luxury of time', you understand how rude and insulting that is to the skilled and experienced developers who volunteer to answer so many questions?

Comment: @MartinJames That is not my intent to insulting the others, Just practically told. I am also a developer contributed stack overflow with 15K points holding. I am not going to insult myself. Think of this question on "CLOSE", if split these and keep asking one by one by one, it is too much for answerer and one cannot get other problems of this. If anybody hurts by this statement, kindly please ignore it.

Comment: *I did already searching on stack overflow and other sites* ... but then you forgot to include the links to the posts you looked at . Had you include them and explained why they don't answer your question it could have helped immensely to clarify your context.

Comment: @rene This i dont know, before asking the question we should add the stackoverflow links that we have already visited. Worth to note, instead of getting them as duplicate from someone. Thanks! will take care

Comment: The Ask Question page offers that guidance: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYssH.png  and you might also like the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: Thanks! @rene I didn't mentioned the links, but i do mentioned what i have tried.

Answer (score 8):

> I see it was decided by single person? Will that be previously by group of people vote then close right?

Yes, holders of a gold tag badge can single handedly close questions as a duplicate. It is a privilege. See [Increase close vote weight for gold tag badge holders](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865)

> Why there is no time interval to questioner to improve their answer before anyone decides on closing it?

Before you asked the question you had plenty of time to improve / research it. Do not post questions and then have an back-and-forth to get the question into shape.

> why we are allowing multiple duplicates allowed to add? This makes even the reviewer not knowing the exact duplicates they are adding. :(

Because we want future visitors to find the answers to your question. If more duplicate target exists with slightly different contexts it is extremely helpful for future visitors to get directed to those different contexts. See [Gold tag-badge holders and moderators can now edit duplicate links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links)

> Will it be feasible to tag/@mention like moderator in such situation that needs help?

Moderators will not be of any help here. They are not subject matter experts. You can @-mention the gold badge holder to explain why you think the duplicate doesn't apply but better is to make an edit to your question where you show that none of the answers in the duplicate will solve your question. By doing so it becomes clear you ask something different. See also [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)

Answer (score 2):

1. People that have a gold tag badge in a tag that the question is tagged with are able to singlehandedly close a question. They are also able to edit the duplicate list.
2. Editing your question to improve, and to explain why it is **not** a duplicate of the listed questions, will automatically put it up for review to be re-opened.
3. Because the same question can be asked multiple times, with slight differentiations. You should review all listed duplicates.
4. Yes you can @mention any user that has activity within the post. The @mention will probably not autocomplete when the specific user hasn't commented on the post.